# How to balance inputs to outputs of this directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

The type of graph I'm thinking about is very specific. I've come up with my own name for it: `Iode` (EYE-ode).
It's a play on "I/O" and the electronics terms "anode" and "cathode".

### Iode

An Iode takes a number of items from its associated input nodes and distributes the items evenly to its associated output nodes.

- There may be 1 to N input nodes.
- There may be 1 to M output nodes.
- The edges from input nodes are combined and then split to the output nodes.
- Output nodes are never connected to input nodes.
- When an Iode "ticks" it does the balancing operation on its associated nodes.
- Maximum input per node per tick.
- Maximum output per node per tick.
- Maximum total throughput per tick.

Here is a diagram of how things could be connected (using http://pencil.evolus.vn/):
[image: iode_simple_cases]

Each square is a node. Each node can contain some number.

I'm having difficulty with the algorithm for the Iode tick. I want to maximize throughput, which could be limited in a number of ways.

Here's my initial python attempt on github (https://github.com/voxelv/ioder) specifically in algorithms.py:

```py
def iode_int_tick(iode):
    # Get the amounts per input iode node
    input_amount_per_iode_node = []
    for iode_node in iode.input_nodes:
        input_amount_per_iode_node.append(min(iode_node.amount, iode.speed['input']))

    # Get the amounts per output iode node
    output_amount_per_iode_node = []
    for iode_node in iode.output_nodes:
        output_amount_per_iode_node.append(iode.speed['output'])

    # Get the maximum throughput
    max_thru_speed = int(iode.speed['throughput'])
    input_amount_total = sum(input_amount_per_iode_node)
    output_amount_total = sum(output_amount_per_iode_node)

    # Compare the maximum throughput
    diff_input_thru_max = int(input_amount_total - max_thru_speed)
    diff_output_thru_max = int(output_amount_total - max_thru_speed)

    # Lessen the input if the maximum throughput is smaller
    if diff_input_thru_max > 0:
        for i in xrange(len(iode.input_nodes)):
            pass  # TODO: figure out this

    # Lessen the output if the maximum throughput is smaller
    if diff_output_thru_max > 0:
        for i in xrange(len(iode.input_nodes)):
            pass  # TODO: figure out this

    # Move the numbers from the inputs
    for i, inode in enumerate(iode.input_nodes):
        inode.take(input_amount_per_iode_node[i])

    # Move the numbers into the outputs
    for i, inode in enumerate(iode.output_nodes):
        inode.give(output_amount_per_iode_node[i])
```

I'm trying to figure out what goes inside the for loops that have the `# TODO` comments.

Edit: An example is loaded into main.py and config.py.
The input limit per node is 5
The output limit per node is 5
The maximum throughput is 8

So with two inputs set to 23 and 6, and two outputs set to 4 and 0, the expected result after the tick would be 19 and 2 in the input nodes, and 8 and 4 in the output nodes.

Running the code with `python main.py` results in the following output:

```
Actual:   [18, 1], [9, 5]
Expected: [19, 2], [8, 4]
```

Some more examples:

```
Initial:  [22, 2], [3, 20]
Actual:   [17, 0], [8, 25]
Expected: [17, 0], [7, 23] or [17, 0], [6, 24]
```

The expected could be either of the ones mentioned depending on the order that a remainder would be processed. The maximum throughput limits us to 8, but the maximum input per node limits us to taking 5 from the first input node. Since the second input node only has two, then we can only supply 7 for this tick. The 7 is distributed to the outputs as evenly as possible, with either 3 or 4 going in the first output, and 4 or 3 going into the second output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with an analogy of my problem and was able to understand it better with the analogy.

It's like trying to fill up an ice-cube tray with water.

The way I've structured the `Iode`, there will never be more water than the tray can handle.

Here is my solution:

```
def water_into_ice_tray(water, ice_tray, **kwargs):

    water_to_put = [0 for _ in xrange(len(ice_tray))]
    recursion_ice_tray = [x for x in ice_tray]

    # Debug depth
    if 'depth' in kwargs:
        print kwargs['depth'],
        kwargs['depth'] += 1

    # BASE_CASE: No more water
    if not water > 0:
        # Exit early
        return water_to_put

    # Get slots that have space for more water
    open_slots = []
    for i in xrange(len(ice_tray)):
        if ice_tray[i] > 0:
            open_slots.append(i)

    # BASE_CASE: Not enough water to go around
    if water < len(open_slots):
        # Put 1 more in the first 'water' slots
        for i in xrange(water):
            water_to_put[open_slots[i]] += 1
        # Exit early
        return water_to_put

    # BASE_CASE: Too much water
    if water > sum(ice_tray):
        raise ValueError("Too much water")

    # Attempt to fill each open slot with a distributed amount
    fill_amount = int(math.floor(int(water) / len(open_slots)))
    leftover = int(water) % len(open_slots)
    for slot_index in open_slots:
        # With how much water have we overfilled this slot?
        diff = fill_amount - ice_tray[slot_index]

        if diff >= 0:
            # We tried putting too much water into this slot
            # Calculate how much to put in it
            water_to_put[slot_index] += fill_amount - diff
            # No more water can fit into this slot
            recursion_ice_tray[slot_index] = 0
            # Keep the leftover
            leftover += diff
        else:
            # The slot could hold the water
            water_to_put[slot_index] += fill_amount
            # Some more water can fit into this slot
            recursion_ice_tray[slot_index] = -diff
            # None is leftover

    # Recurse
    recursion_water_to_put = water_into_ice_tray(leftover, recursion_ice_tray, **kwargs)

    # Add up recursion result to this result
    return map(add, water_to_put, recursion_water_to_put)


def iode_int_tick(iode):
    # Calculate available amounts per input node
    available_input_per_node = []
    for inode in iode.input_nodes:
        available_input_per_node.append(min(inode.amount, iode.speed['input']))
    input_limit = sum(available_input_per_node)

    # Get the throughput
    throughput_limit = iode.speed['throughput']

    # Calculate available space per output node
    available_output_per_node = []
    for inode in iode.output_nodes:
        available_output_per_node.append(min(inode.max_amount - inode.amount, iode.speed['output']))
    output_limit = sum(available_output_per_node)

    # Decide which is the limiting factor
    limiter = min(input_limit, throughput_limit, output_limit)

    if limiter == input_limit:
        # If the input limits, then distribute to the outputs. The throughput can handle it.
        amount_to_take_per_input_node = available_input_per_node
        amount_to_put_per_output_node = water_into_ice_tray(input_limit, available_output_per_node)
        pass

    elif limiter == throughput_limit:
        # If throughput limits, then distribute the throughput amount from the inputs, to the outputs.
        amount_to_take_per_input_node = water_into_ice_tray(throughput_limit, available_input_per_node)
        amount_to_put_per_output_node = water_into_ice_tray(throughput_limit, available_output_per_node)
        pass

    elif limiter == output_limit:
        # If output limits, then distribute the draw on the inputs. The throughput can handle it.
        amount_to_take_per_input_node = water_into_ice_tray(output_limit, available_input_per_node)
        amount_to_put_per_output_node = available_output_per_node
        pass
    else:
        raise ValueError("Somehow the limiting factor is something other than the input, throughput, or output.")

    # Do the taking
    for i in xrange(len(iode.input_nodes)):
        iode.input_nodes[i].take(amount_to_take_per_input_node[i])

    # Do the giving
    for i in xrange(len(iode.output_nodes)):
        iode.output_nodes[i].give(amount_to_put_per_output_node[i])
```